# kubernetes cluster installation: connection refused when joining nodes to master

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to install a kubernetes cluster, one server and two slaves running Ubuntu 16.04, following the instructions in this [article](https://medium.com/@SystemMining/setup-kubenetes-cluster-on-ubuntu-16-04-with-kubeadm-336f4061d929)

when arriving at the steps to join slave nodes to the master, I perform (as suggested by the `kubeadm init` output step) the following command:

```
sudo kubeadm join <master ip>:6443 --token 6wz<...etc...>goj --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:ac3<...etc...>54a
```

Here, I get an error

```
.
.
.
[discovery] Trying to connect to API Server "<master ip>:6443"
[discovery] Created cluster-info discovery client, requesting info from "https://<master ip>:6443"
[discovery] Failed to request cluster info, will try again: [Get https://<master ip>:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info: 
    dial tcp <master ip>:6443: getsockopt: connection refused]
.
.
.
```

My questions are:

- how can I check that the master is correctly running? (`kubeadm init` printed a message `Your Kubernetes master has initialized successfully!`, but I don't know how to actually check this is true)
- what could cause the connection refused error?
- could the error depend on the docker version? (during `kubeadm init` I got a wanring `docker version is greater than the most recently validated version. Docker version: 17.05.0-ce. Max validated version: 17.03`, don't know if this could be related to my problem)

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you change your TLS certificates on your apiserver. You will have invalid tokens on your service account and would have to delete and make one again. Do this:

```
 kubectl delete serviceaccount default
 kubectl delete serviceaccount --namespace=kube-system default
```

You can verify if your master node is successfully hosted by. This will let you know your master-url-dns.

```
kubectl cluster-info
```

Comment: when launching the delete serviceaccount I got the error message `Error from server (MethodNotAllowed): the server does not allow this method on the requested resource (delete serviceaccounts default)`, with the cluster-info command I get the following output::
 `Kubernetes master is running at http://localhost:8080
 
 To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
 error: serializer for text/html;charset=utf-8 doesn't exist`

Comment: It seems you don't have valid credentials for your kubectl client. It depends on how is auth configured in your cluster, what you need for auth. Most tools, though, install credentials for kubectl when you run them. How did you install the cluster?

Comment: as I mentioned in the post, I simply followed the instructions contained in the linked article